# Stringification of a variable value

Tags: gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
#define SATA_PORT_0   "/sata-ahci/port0"
#define SATA_PORT_1   "/sata-ahci/port1"
#define SATA_PORT_2   "/sata-ahci/port2"
#define SATA_PORT_3   "/sata-ahci/port3"
#define SATA_PORT_4   "/sata-ahci/port4"
#define SATA_PORT_5   "/sata-ahci/port5"

#define SATA_NODE(p)  HOW TO DEFINE THIS?!!

int main() 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", i, SATA_NODE(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Question: how to define above macro, to get string print out in GCC ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't readily do it with a macro.

The problem is that a macro is a compile time construct, and the loop you have there is a run time construct; you can't do it directly.

You could investigate [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) (which is not specifically for C++; it also works with the C preprocessor) and use that to write macros which generate the loop.

You could hand unroll the loop and use a macro with a constant argument:

```
#define SATA_PORT(i) "/sata-ahci/port" #i

printf("%s\n", 0, SATA_PORT(0));
printf("%s\n", 1, SATA_PORT(1));
printf("%s\n", 2, SATA_PORT(2));
printf("%s\n", 3, SATA_PORT(3));
printf("%s\n", 4, SATA_PORT(4));
printf("%s\n", 5, SATA_PORT(5));
```

Or you can use an array of strings (also suggested by a now-deleted answer).

```
#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

const char * const sata_ports[] = 
{
    "/sata-ahci/port0",
    "/sata-ahci/port1",
    "/sata-ahci/port2",
    "/sata-ahci/port3",
    "/sata-ahci/port4",
    "/sata-ahci/port5"
};

for (int i = 0; i < DIM(sata_ports); i++)
    printf("%d %s\n", i, sata_ports[i]);
```

Comment: #define SATA_NODE(p)    ((p==0)?"/sata-ahci/port0":ISP1(p))
#define ISP1(p)         ((p==1)?"/sata-ahci/port1":ISP2(p))
#define ISP2(p)         ((p==2)?"/sata-ahci/port2":ISP3(p))
#define ISP3(p)         ((p==3)?"/sata-ahci/port3":ISP4(p))
#define ISP4(p)         ((p==4)?"/sata-ahci/port4":ISP5(p))

Answer (score 1):

In the C language you can't.  Macro substitution occurs before ordinary compilation.  The preprocessor doesn't know that preprocessing token i is going to be declared as an int later during ordinary compilation.

Execution comes even later.  The compiler can figure out that i is going to have values ranging from 0 to 5, but that doesn't help you.  The actual assignments occur during execution, which is after compilation finished, which is after preprocessing finished.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for above answers. I found a way to do this myself.

```
#define SATA_PORT(p) (p==0)?SATA_PORT_0:ISP1
#define ISP1         (p==1)?SATA_PORT_1:ISP2
...
```

In some situations, the above macro makes the code much better.

Comment: Each to their own, I suppose.  I wouldn't touch this with a bargepole, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've made solution a little bit nicer (because of availability of [compound statements](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) in GCC compiler).

If i had similar problem I would solve it like this:

```
#define SATA_PORT(p) ({char prt[100]; sprintf(prt, "/sata-ahci/port%d", p); prt;})
```

And BTW you forgot `printf` format specifier for variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need(ed):

```
#define STRINGIFY(x)                #x
#define TOSTRING(x)                 STRINGIFY(x)
#define SATA_NODE_TO_SATA_PORT(p)   SATA_PORT_##p
#define SATA_NODE(p)                TOSTRING(SATA_NODE_TO_SATA_PORT(p))
```

Then, if you try to print the preprocessed macros with:

```
std::cout << SATA_NODE(3) << " - " << SATA_NODE(5) << std::endl;
std::cout << SATA_NODE(7) << std::endl;
```

what you get is:

```
"/sata-ahci/port3" - "/sata-ahci/port5"
SATA_PORT_7
```